# Predective (Quick type) keyboard not displaying in iPhone6, 6+ simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard, ios8

In my application there is no predictive keyboard showing in simulator.
From setting, It's already ON for predictive keyboard option.
For this same application and same screen, there is predictive keyboard showing on iPhone 6+ device.
Not sure why not there in simulator

If needed below info which i am using:

**Xcode 6.0.1**

**iOS 8.0**

**iPhone 6+ simulator**

**OSX 10.10 Yosemite**

If these helps to make any setting change.
I have also found one [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6548860) to make it on, But not working on my case.
As per this link I have attached my screen show of simulator.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set the autocorrection attribute of your text field to be UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault or UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes to see the predictive feature